# SOAP Put Request Using WSDL

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I have been asked by a friend for some help with his boss' website. I have literally no knowledge of SOAP and was wondering if someone can point me in the right direction. I have looked for tutorials but I am really stuck.

I have been given an XML file and need to PUT this information to a SOAP service using WSDL. I have been given a username and password for this so my PHP script will need to use authentication of some kind right?

I have tried already to connect to the WSDL given to me but I keep getting this error.

```
Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://compassqa.cengage.com:4502/cdes/services/cdes_ws?wsdl' : Extra content at the end of the document in /home/birdnetw/public_html/zesty-designs.co.uk/misc/soap-test/put.php on line 10
```

My code looks like this at the moment. I have more but it's a complete mess so commented it out for now.

```
$wdsl = "https://compassqa.cengage.com:4502/cdes/services/cdes_ws?wsdl";
    $client = new SoapClient($wdsl, array(
        "login" => "****",
        "password" => "***",
        "trace" => 1,
        "exceptions" => 0));
```

I'm not asking for someone to hold my hand but if you could just point me in the right direction that would be grand.

Comment: Actually the error gives you some hint, look on line 10 in your code.

Comment: Line 10 is '"exceptions" => 0));' - I tried the same code with a different URL for another WDSL sheet and it worked fine. Maybe it is something to do with the remote URL being SSL?

Comment: Yes it might be the SSL connection, or it may be a network problem with the WDSL.

Comment: If it is the SSL connection. How can I check for sure? And is there a way around it?